# Getting List of AD group members powershell error

Tags: powershell

I am trying to extract the list of users with powershell, ive tried two things:

1) `Get-ADGroupmember -identity "group name" | select name | Export-Csv -path H:\test\testcsv.csv`

with error

```
PS H:\> Get-ADGroupmember -identity "group name" | select name | Export-Csv -path H:\test\testcsv.csv
Get-ADGroupmember : Cannot find an object with identity: 'group name' under: 'DC=oak,DC=leaf,DC=pine,DC=maple'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ADGroupmember -identity "group name" | select name | E ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (group name:ADGroup) [Get-ADGroupMember], ADIdentityNotFoundE
   xception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException,M
   icrosoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroupMember
```

2) `dsquery group -name “group name” | dsget group -members > H:\test\testcsv.csv`

with error:

`dsget failed:'Target object for this command' is missing.
type dsget /? for help.`

[image]

Can anyone help with this?

Thanks.

Comment: The errors tend to suggest a group named "group name" does not exist in the domain

Comment: As aside: in your second attempt, you are using curly quotes `“”` and you shoud replace them with straight ones. They may look nice in a Word document, but never use them with code.

Comment: @Itchydon is there a way to check which domain it belong to?

Comment: To find out out what domain it is in you would need to target a global catalag server

Comment: Something like this should do it: `get-adgroup -filter "name -like 'Group Name'" -server globalCatalog:3268`

Comment: replace `globalCatalog` with the actual domain controller name

Comment: sorry for the newbness, where can I find actual domain controller name?

Comment: `get-addomaincontroller | select name,isglobalcatalog` will get you a single domain controller name or `get-addomaincontroller -filter * | select name,isglobalcatalog` will get you all the dc names in the domain